# Passing a specific class argument to a Java Generic Function

Tags: java, generics, hashmap, hashset

So, I'm new to Java Generics. I'm building a graph and an adjacency list using hashMap and hashSet. I've written the class and its methods using Generics. I've also extended T to Node.
For printing the adjacency list,

```
public class Graph<T extends Node>{

    public static int time;

    private HashMap<T, HashSet<T>> adjacencyList;

    public Graph(){
        this.adjacencyList = new HashMap<>();
    }

    void printAdjacencyList(HashMap<T,HashSet<T>> adj){
        for(T n : adj.keySet()){
            System.out.print("Key: " + n.getValue()+"\t");
            Iterator<T> i = adj.get(n).iterator();
            while(i.hasNext()){
                System.out.print(" "+i.next().getValue());
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

```
public static void main(String[] args){
        Graph<Node> G = new Graph<>();
                                             // have added vertices and edges
        printAdjacencyList(G.adjacencyList);
}
```

Here,**G.adjacencyList** is of the type **HashMap<Node,HashSet< Node >>** .
Node is another class with a few members.

But , I'm encountering compilation error:
*The method printAdjacencyList(HashMap<T,HashSet < T >>) in the type Graph is not applicable for the arguments (HashMap<Node,HashSet < Node >>)*

So, as far as I can understand it's saying me to explicitly write a function with **HashMap<Node, HashSet < Node > >** as arguments.
Is there any way that I can use the generic function somehow (instead of writing a new function with required arguments).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you want to pass a `HashMap<Node, Set>` but it want a `HastMap<Node, HastSet>`.

Every `HashSet` also fulfill the requirement of `Set` but not vice versa.

Solution 1:

`void printAdjacencyList(HashMap<T,HashSet<T>> adj){` =>

`void printAdjacencyList(HashMap<T,Set<T>> adj){`

Solution 2:

`private HashMap<T, Set<T>> adjacencyList;` => `private HashMap<T, HashSet<T>> adjacencyList;`

Comment: Sorry for the typo, i want HashMap<Node,HashSet<Node>>> to be passed to a function which takes input argument as HashMap<T,HashSet<T>>.

Comment: But what you do here, is pass a `Set` to a function which need a `HastSet`. This doesn't work because a HastSet is more complex than a Set. You can pass `HashSet` to a method that wants a `Set`. However you cannot pass a Set to a HastSet because Set is more primitive than a HastSet

Comment: Ok. I understand. I've edited the question. But the problem I have is passing HashMap<Node,HashSet<Node>> to function with HashMap<T,HashSet<T>> as argument.